# type two fields simultaneously in jquery.dataTable

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I'm working on how to type simultaneously in two fields one is on my  and ther receiver of input is the SEARCH FIELD of jquery.dataTable

So far this is my code. It works perfect on my two fields but when I try it to the jquery dataTable SEARCH FILED it doesn't work.

Hope someone will help me. Thank you in advance .

BTW here is my code.

```
    <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="date">ACCOUNT NAME:</label><br>
                 <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="accounts" name="accounts" value="" required> -->
                  <textarea rows="6" cols="50" class="form-control" id="accounts" name="accounts" maxlength="300" value="" onkeyup="change();" required></textarea>
               </div><!-- /.form group -->

  <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="date">Manpower Requirements:</label><br>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="man_req" value="" name="man_req">
                 </div><!-- /.form group -->
```

And here is my script.

```
function change(){
                var src= document.getElementById("accounts");
                var dest= document.getElementById("man_req");
                dest.value=src.value;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Datatables [search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) Api.

```
table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

function change(){    
  var src= document.getElementById("accounts");    
  var dest= document.getElementById("man_req");    
  dest.value=src.value; 
  table.search( src.value ).draw(); 
}
```